# Do not include few parent class elements when XML constructed from child

Tags: jaxb

Is it possible to not have few fields from parent class when XML is constructed out of the child class?
But the elements should be present when XML is constructed from parent class?

Example

Parent class

```
    @XmlRootElement(name = "location")
    @XmlType(propOrder = { "id", "name" })
    @JsonPropertyOrder({ "id", "name" })
    public class Parent {

    private Integer id;
    private String name;

    @XmlElement(name = "id", nillable = true)
    @JsonProperty("id")
    public Integer getId() {
        return super.getId();
    }

    @JsonProperty("id")
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        super.setId(id);
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "name", nillable = true)
    @JsonProperty("name")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @JsonProperty("name")
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

Child class

@XmlRootElement(name = "location")
@XmlType(propOrder = { "id" })
@JsonPropertyOrder({ "id" })
public class Child extends Parent {

    @XmlElement(name = "id", nillable = true)
    @JsonProperty("id")
    public Integer getId() {
        return super.getId();
    }

    @JsonProperty("id")
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        super.setId(id);
    }
}
```

I do not want the name field when XML is constructed from child class. However it should be present when XML is constructed from parent class.

Answer (score 0):

Try to override the getter and setter for `name` in the subclass and annotate them with `@JsonIgnore` and/or `@XmlTransient`.

EDIT

Indeed, `@XmlTransient` does not work with polymorphism as I expected (and as `@JsonIgnore` do). What you can try is:

-- move all content of `Parent` class to an abstract `Base` class
-- mark `Base` as `@XmlTransient`
-- make `Parent` extend `Base` and add no content to it
-- make `Child` extend `Base`

Here is some synthetic example I worked on. It can easily be translated to your particular classes.

Class `Base`

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "location")
@XmlSeeAlso(value = {Parent.class, Child.class})
@XmlTransient
public abstract class Base {
private String a;
private String b;

@XmlElement(name = "a")
public String getA() {
    return a;
}
public void setA(String a) {
    this.a = a;
}

@XmlElement(name = "b", nillable = true)
public String getB() {
    return b;
}
public void setB(String b) {
    this.b = b;
}
}
```

Class `Parent`

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "location")
@XmlType
public class Parent extends Base {

}
```

Class `Child`

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "location")
@XmlType
public class Child extends Base {
private String c;

@XmlElement(name = "c")
public String getC() {
    return c;
}

public void setC(String c) {
    this.c = c;
}

@Override
@XmlTransient
public String getB(){
    return super.getB();
}

@Override
public void setB(String b) {
    super.setB(b);
}

}
```

Obviously, if the class hierarchy grows larger, it may be harder to maintain such a workaround. In those cases, you may think about choosing composition rather than inheritance.

Comment: JsonIgnore works. i.e when the format is JSON the name element is not present in the output. But when the format is xml the name element is still present though i have the XmlTransient and Override for the getter in the subclass

Comment: There's no quick solution. See my edited answer for an additional solution I found.